# ImageView invisible when using color for background android

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I'd like to a create an `ImageView` which is fill the whole screen. And I'd like to make this `ImageView` to have a color (green,black,transparent etc.). 
I faced with a problem which is wierd to me because the problem is, when I set the `ImageView` background for an image using `@drawable` resources then it's looking good, but when I using `@color`resources then the `ImageView` is invisble. How is it possible?

Check xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cimtext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Cím: "
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFD700" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal2"
    android:background="#FFD700"/>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout"
    android:clickable="true">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ek_logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way I can see ek_logo picture on the screen but when I change that line `android:background="@drawable/ek_logo"` into this `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>` there is nothing I can see.
I hope you could help me.

Comment: what is you r colorPrimary

Comment: `<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>`  this is it

Comment: you will get a blue screen

Comment: @V V No, no I won't thats why I asked this quesiton.

Comment: @drawable/background whats inside this

Comment: @eLemEnt it's just an image for background.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/ek_logo" shows image but  android:background="@color/colorPrimary" shows nothing thats you problem

Comment: Have you tried to set that programmatically ??

Comment: @V V  You said before that I should get a blue screen. Now I don't understand what you are trying to say. So it is not possible to add color for a View with this  `ndroid:background="@color/colorPrimary" ` ?

Comment: @eLemEnt No I don't because I need to put this `ImageView` over a the map fragment with transparent color to handle the ScrollViews separated. I'd like to do it in xml if it's possible.

Comment: if you add android:background="@color/colorPrimary" you will get a blue screen only because the image is match parent. what is your actual problem

Comment: @V V ok. Then could you tell me how can I show a color of an `ImageView` ? It's possible isn't?

Comment: @J.Doe please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@J Doe.

change your `layout_height` for `ImageView` also since your using `Relative Layout` specify below which view you have to display `ImageView`. Also if you want to align ImageView on the top of map fragment then use `android:layout_alignTop`

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Comment: @J.Doe glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

You should only set an ImageView's content with:

```
android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
```

If you just want a background color behind your image, simply change the root view's background color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">
```

Then, whenever you only want to see the color , just set the visibility of the ImageView to GONE or INVISIBLE

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE
```

or:

```
imageView.setImageResource(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's not what I'd like to use the `ImageView` . The point is that I'd like to put this `ImageView` over the map with transparent color and then I could handle the touch of the map. Because the map has scroll ability and the layout has too.

Comment: I think the effect is the same if you set the alpha of the map instead of another view over this map.

Comment: But wait, have you tried  android:src   yet by the way ?

Comment: both android:src and android:background work when I give it a color.

Comment: It's very interesting. When I run the app on another device it's working fine. Even if I use lower or higher API level.

Comment: Which device is it ? It is never a bad idea to test your app on several different brands (Samsung, LG, HTC, etc)
I find plenty of flaws sometimes

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```